# What does @ do in Python 3 (Pyglet)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyglet

I was trying out Pyglet via [this tutorial](http://pyglet.org/doc-current/programming_guide/quickstart.html#image-viewer) when I noticed this portion of the code, which is not documented on the page.. I have not been able to find anything on it by searching the web either.

What exactly does it do? Can it be used with other objects?

```
    @window.event
```

Comment: It’s a [decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators).

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python/1594484#1594484)

Comment: Thank you both for clearing this up for me (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It "decorates" the following function/method/class

```
@window.event
def f(foo):
    return bar
```

Is equivalent to

```
def f(foo):
    return bar
f = window.event(f)
```